# how to connect RFID REader with computer through LAN cable

Tags: rfid

We wish to connect FEIG RFID reader with computer via LAN. 
The RFID model is LRU1002.The RFID interfacing software is ISO start 2017. I followed the instruction manual but couldn't succeed in that.
Can someone guide us how to establish the connection? This question is out of programming but i guess people in this forum might guide for troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: Contact the support who supplied the hardware and software.

Answer (score 0):

Connection between Reader and PC via LAN can be made simple while configuring the IP address of your PC as match with IP address of RFID reader. For Ex. my RFID reader ip is 192.168.10.10. Therefore, i have changed my PC ip address into 192.168.10.xx.Hope this can be helpful for someone as the simple task takes my 2 to 3 hrs.